# How to pass a list with an absent value to Python through the command line

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I've been using `argparse` to run Python scripts from the command line.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-foo', type = str, nargs = '*')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

From the command line, this would allow me to write something like:

`python myscript.py -foo "value A" "value B" "value C"`

which in python would become

`['value A', 'value B', 'value C']`

But now what if I wanted to pass along a missing value in that list? Such as:

`['value A', None, 'value C']`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

None cannot be achieved, as far as I know. `argv` will always be list of strings, so "most empty" is empty string `""`: `python myscript.py -foo "value A" "" "value C"`

Edit:

turns out you can pass any callable that takes 1 string argument to `type` argument of `add_argument`. For example, if you wanted to treat empty string as `None`, and any other value as `float`:

```
import argparse

def nullable_float(str):
    if str == "":
        return None
    else:
        return float(str)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-foo', type = nullable_float, nargs = '*')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Thanks. What if this was a list of numbers instead? Would a non-existent value be possible then?

Comment: If you pass numbers in command line to python script, they will still be treated as string (saved in `argv` list as strings)

Comment: Even if I used, for instance

`parser.add_argument('-foo', type = float, nargs = '*')`
?

Comment: Sorry, I am maybe answering something completely different that you asked. I was looking at sys.argv. I'll try to update answer. But I suppose the point for strings still stands. On command line level, you always pass strings, so it cannot be None. argparse would have to convert it from some other value.

Comment: @AndyPL, `sys.argv` contains strings which the shell (`bash`) parsed from your command line.  `argparse` parses that list of strings.  If  you specify a `type`, it passes each string through that function.  If `type=float` then the strings will have to represent valid floats. for example `float("123.34")`.  You could try `float("nan")`.

Comment: I edited the answer, however I am not sure if it is suitable for your problem. Wouldnt it be sufficient to specify some neutral value (for example 0), and treat that as 0.0? argparse's input is sys.argv, and that is list of strings. So there always has to be some value (at least `""`).

Comment: Thanks guys! Passing `""` for a substitute `None` for strings, and using `"nan"` for floats works for my purposes. Unfortunately, `"nan"` doesn't work for `type = int` though.